# MySQL client portability for my C# app

Tags: c#, mysql

I am building an application which needs to connect to a central MySQL database. The application is written in C#. I have installed the .NET connector from MySQL for the VS integration.

I was wondering if there is anything special I need to do to be able to have my application be portable and not require an install of the connector on every machine it is used on?

There is a similar question I found here on SO, but it is for a server instead instead of client which is very different.

Edit:

Connector I used: .NET connector 6.2.3 (
http://www.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/)

Comment: Please be more precise which connector you use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you make an installer, you can include the dll for the mysql connecter such that it is copied along with the other side. This way, whenever the application is installed properly, you wont have the problem.